# Parent Window in New Tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a pop up, let's call it "B", and the main window (where the pop up came from) for "A". The third is the link on B, and I need this to open in a new tab, in A, from B. So I want to open a link in a new tab on the parent window from a pop up (the child window).

I know someone's question is quite similar, but it did not answer my question. Please help :)

Comment: and `<a ... target="_blank"></a>` doesn't work?

Comment: `window.opener.open(url);` should work if A and B are on the same domainname.

Comment: PS no need to add your email address. If you ask a question here people will answer it here, so other people with a similar problem can find the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, from the child window:

```
window.opener.document.append("<a href='http://whateva' target='_blank' />").click();
```

Comment: If the opening tab has been closed, ```window.opener``` is ```null```.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do `<a target="_new">`.

According to the end-users browser settings it will either open a new WINDOW and or TAB.